# Mongo: Is MongoClient.connection just shorthand for new MongoClient(new Server())?

Tags: mongodb

In the [MongoDocs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) they specify this is the correct way to create an open connection:

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , Server = require('mongodb').Server;

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb");

  mongoClient.close();
});
```

But later they mention that you can also do it this way:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, db) {
  test.equal(null, err);
  test.ok(db != null);
});
```

They never explicitly say the difference between the two though. It seems like the second version is just a shorthand for the first. Is this true or is there something else I am not getting here?

Comment: Yes, I think there's no substantive difference between the two. In the most current versions of the driver, the [API for MongoClient](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html) only has `connect`, so I think it's part of some philosophical shift on the part of the developers. Closing connections is now part of closing a `db` object instead of a `MongoClient`.

Comment: Thanks. How come you replied as a comment instead of an answer? I would mark this as correct if I could.